# How to retrieve access token value in flutter

Tags: javascript, http, split, dart, flutter

I have this codes to get access token:

```
       Future<Null> getData() async {

            var url = "http://192.168.1.23:7070/api/v2/token";
            http.post(url, body:{
              "grant_type": "string",
              "branchcode": "string",
              "password": "string",
              "username": "string",
              "dbname": "string",
              "dbuser": "string",
              "dbpassword": "string",
              "dbtype": "string"
            }).then((response){
              print("Response Status: ${response.statusCode}");
              print("Response Body: ${response.body}");
            });
        }
```

And after run this code block it returns something like this:

```
Response Body: {"access_token":"AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE_Cl-sBAAAAgUTYyajkrEKWAWNrBvgpHQAAAAACAAAAAAAQZgAAAAEAACAAAAB-c92RaHBUfb0aNvnWFqx3JW29bBeQPIouZVDHsTsg8QAAAAAOgAAAAAIAACAAAAC7JdwAlRh8ckP3gAG4vc6H-nULfmjfpBF-gleCcFXeFzABAACJft4ZnsMt1clpRHUTAbiWQIqo5Zmt7_Qc7-pDPwA33O7z3VgFhkx2ITLn5xWGKcVHTkxOxPeRe4qrgEDbsd8V6DHcuwirPkAZye5zECUllxE6IDkNetLkTQsLuK2CpSWxAksFzUS6vhiU7fqkNKsXegtOV--0wFzWsq-ikTjYWnr4LsdAiSUfy_HsTMvLxoIjIqDSxw0QyMM1I2eVIE2wSsZSpoYn3CQIGejQAlG_mUIgzt3PBqEZ6kqIX-Qhx4jpcypUOG5GFNMKLUJa5mti1UiTi8ETpVN_8y_tDhVi-9AS2MJpJN7-Gao_fIB5s0yaH_m9fHkwFgXF1N-Y5GevDypdNryQWbHXQkf88DKZnljMSGzJkJhpzls3PTN8iwss32CXbeO1zaWm-iJAgMK_QAAAACVQGecH57e1QB-FRu2iCt-d6x37x6MJ-_H_H8uYOKbZYBX0lA1b8WxteCLWPM5mAJR1p3tHE_VBqQqvS4pKGHM","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":1199,"refresh_token":"f8de12c7a90b401b9400b93b4cf2c128"
```

My question is, how to retrieve the value of "access_token" in this code blocks?

Comment: What do you mean by split?

Comment: ı want to retrieve just access_token value. Sorry !

Comment: JSON.parse(response.body).access_token ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the response in the following ways

1.If it's from response headers you can access it by using

```
response.headers['access-token']
```

2.If it's from response body you can access it by using

```
  print('access token is -> ${json.decode(response.body)['access_token']}');
```

3.If you are getting the object you can parse it and cast to required type by using this

```
final Map<String, dynamic> data = json.decode(response.body)['user'].cast<String, dynamic>();
```